Left or right for 2 points on a line, clockwise or counterclockwise for 3 points in the plane. What is the analogue for 4 points in space?
For $a, b \in \mathbb{R},$ there is a notion of left or right. As a society, we agreed $a$ is left of $b$ if $a<b$ and otherwise $a$ is right of $b.$ It could've been the other way and nothing would've changed.
For $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}^2,$ there is a notion of clockwise or counterclockwise. As a society, we agreed whether $a \to b \to c \to a$ is a clockwise or counterclockwise loop depending on the positions of $a, b, c.$ The unit circle $C$ traveling $1 \to i \to -1 \to 1$ is counterclockwise. To formally test 3 points, translate $a$ to $1,$ dilate and rotate so that $b = e^{i\theta}, c = e^{i \phi}$ with $\theta, \phi \in (0, 2\pi),$ and see whether $\theta$ is left or right of $\phi.$ In reality, we visually traverse the loop and don't need this.
There is no natural way to create a single object from $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{R}^3$ in a fair and equal manner to each point such that it has two possible orientations and it's easy to distinguish which is which.
I'm aware that we may orient $x_0, x_1, \dots, x_n \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ by considering the points as an $n$-simplex and for every $k \ge 2,$ orienting the $(k-1)$-faces such that every $(k-2)$-face has opposite orientations in the two $(k-1)$-faces it's part of, proceeding inductively.
For $\mathbb{R}^3,$ this process spits out 4 loops, one for each face of the tetrahedron with vertices $a, b, c, d.$ When viewing the tetrahedron from the outside, every face has the same orientation, so luckily we can define orientation to just be the orientation of a single face.
My issue with this answer is it feels like we no longer have a single object. In 1D, we had a single ray. In 2D, we had a single loop. In 3D, we had 4 loops and have to rememeber the tetrahedron when relying on the cheap trick of every loop being the same. I consider it a cheap trick because in 2D, we can erase the vertices of the triangle and the loop will sit on its own.
Couldn't there be a way of drawing just one squiggle traveling through all 4 points in a fair way or shading in one surface patch containing all 4 points which represents the orientation?

I think the words are direct/indirect ; see this picture, it is associated to this question. : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A8gle_de_la_main_droite#/media/Fichier:Main_droite_3T.jpg

You got it. It is known as Right-hand-Rule. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule

@Lourrran I am looking for a way to take an object with 4 points and produce an orientation. This takes 2 vectors and produces a perpendicular vector, which is different. Also, it doesn't work because in many cases I can use either hand, even with the same fingers, to line up 4 points.

You have 4 points, ordered, A,B,C,D ; A is the palm of your hand, your thumb points toward B, your Index points towards C, and your middle-finger points to D ; if you can do this with your right hand, ABCD is considered as direct. Else, if you need your left hand to do this, ABCD is considered as indirect.

You can clap your hands together, line up your fingers, and move them around in many ways. Furthermore, both palms will be used. An extra condition is needed. @Lourrran

This rule is used by many people, since more than 1 century, in many domains (especially electromagnetism). It works fine. If (AB,AC,AD) matches with you right hand, then (AB,AD, AC) will match with your left hand. But (AB,AC,AD) will not match with your left hand. This rule can be used to generate a DIRECT vector with 2 non linears vectors, and it can be used in opposite way, to check if 4 points generate a direct quaternion or indirect quaternion.

@Lourrran See how spongebob's hands are together in this image? You can use both the left and the right hand to point at the same 4 points A, B, C, D: https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.497394617.2131/bg,f8f8f8-flat,750x,075,f-pad,750x1000,f8f8f8.u2.webp

@Displayname You didn't follow the link to Wikipedia, did you? For the right-hand rule, you hold your fingers as in this picture from the article. But this doesn't strike me as a useful notation of the kind you requested. It's too hard to draw!

@DavidK Yes, and you can hold either hand like that in some cases. I agree it's not useful.

I don't know about you, if I put my right hand into the right-hand-rule configuration, and point my left thumb and forefinger in the same direction as my right hand and forefinger, the middle finger on my left hand can't point in the same direction as the middle finger on my right hand. There is a reason we call one chirality "right handed" and the other "left handed." If that doesn't make sense then I'm not sure how 3-forms, which would be the next step, would make sense either.

@DavidK I tried it right now and had no trouble when my fingers were close enough. Of course, if my forefinger and middle finger are far enough apart, it's impossible.
